# Interpreting a clause beginning with "It would happen that..."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have come across the following clause in "The Corrections" by Franzen:

> It would happen that the First and Second Notices were underground somewhere.

I am not sure how to interpret this construction. How does it compare to constructions such as "It happened that...", "It could happen that..." or the simpler "The First and Second Notices were underground somewhere"?

Comment: I think we need more context: what the heck are "First and Second Notices"? Are we meant to read this with emphasis on the "would", i.e. is Franzen being sarcastic about something? (Again, we'd need to know what the heck these capital-N Notices *are* to begin to assign any meaning to the sentence.) I just noticed you labeled the quote a "clause": is this actually a part of a longer sentence? If yes, what is the entire sentence?

Comment: @Marthaª: The relevant passage is in a link under my answer, but trust me - the meaning of "Notices" (or indeed, "underground") aren't in the least relevant to the either meaning or the stylistic acceptability of starting a sentence with *"It would happen that "*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More common usages are...

> [*"**Sometimes** it would happen [that something would occur]"*.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sometimes%20it%20would%20happen%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

There are also plenty of instances of ["**often** it would happen"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sometimes%20it%20would%20happen%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22often%20it%20would%20happen%22&oq=%22often%20it%20would%20happen%22&gs_l=serp.3...21293.24450.0.24938.14.14.0.0.0.1.145.1374.10j4.14.0...0.0...1c.1.sIpEXYBOlAI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cd2c56685dba42a2&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=893) (or even [oftentimes...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sometimes%20it%20would%20happen%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oftentimes%20it%20would%20happen%22&oq=%22oftentimes%20it%20would%20happen%22&gs_l=serp.3...44282.45200.1.45736.5.5.0.0.0.0.99.439.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.dhLrOlTK3AM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cd2c56685dba42a2&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=893)). Stylistically it's slightly "unusual" to start the sentence with just OP's "unqualified" version - I can't see anything inherently wrong, but it does sound even more "rustic/dated" to me than the standard versions.

OP's alternatives wouldn't convey the same meaning. The original doesn't say the Notices were underground on any specific occasion being referenced - it just says that on any given occasion, *they **might** be*.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. Franzen confused me when he abruptly switched from referencing to two specific first and second notices to referencing to first and second notices in general.

Comment: @Missing Bob: I have absolutely no idea what those "Notices" are, or what it would mean for them to be "underground" sometimes. Nor indeed, whether the First and Second Notices on any given day are still "the same" Notices on a different day. But I don't think that makes any difference to the meaning of the *"it would happen"* construction.

Comment: ... belay that! I [found the passage](http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/2001/nov/22/firstchapters.reviews), wherein I see it's preceded by *a threatening Third Notice from a medical lab that demanded immediate payment of $0.22 while simultaneously showing an account balance of $0.00 carried forward*. The word "Notice" (and the capitalisation thereof) is being used rather quirkily. I couldn't really endorse that text as "typical modern-day English" - it seems somewhat "literary", and maybe a bit "poetic" in overall tone.

Comment: It could also be a rueful statement, expressing annoyance at the obstinacy or inopportune nature of fate in this particular circumstance.

Comment: @Robusto: Possibly. But look at the very next sentence: *She might suspect, perhaps, the family-room closet, but the governing force, in the person of Alfred, would be watching a network newsmagazine at a volume thunderous enough to keep him awake, and he had every light in the family room burning, and there was a non-negligible possibility that if she opened the closet door a cascade of catalogues and House Beautifuls and miscellaneous Merrill Lynch statements would come toppling and sliding out, incurring Alfred's wrath.* Now that's **some sentence!**

Comment: I am sure that you are right. It all makes sense to me now. I am probably only confusing you with my unnecessary explanation. EDIT: I see you found the passage while I was writing this post :)

Comment: @Missing Bob: I think it's potentially quite an interesting question - so far as I'm aware, the "bare" intro *"It would happen [that...]"* invariably implies *sometimes* (less frequently, *[quite] often*), but maybe others don't think so. Except in Robusto's "exasperation" context, where the word **would** would always be heavily emphasised in speech, and should therefore be italicised in writing. But you should try to find and include a link to a fuller context when you ask things like this.

Comment: Ok, I will remember that. I am not sure how much I am allowed to transcribe without violating any copyright, if there's no online source, but I will do my best. I think Franzen is making a "poetic point" through being ambiguous about whether he is describing a specific scenario or repeated scenarios. I really like Franzen's prose and am therefore learning this first chapter, which I like particularly much, by heart.

Comment: I can't believe you could copy enough text into an ELU question to have anyone worry about violation of copyright, but I meant *post a link*, not *replicate vast amounts of text here*. Whatever - obviously The Guardian newspaper didn't see a problem in posting that extract I linked to, which runs to several pages (perhaps they figured that if you count the number of ***sentences***, it's not that many! :)

Comment: ...for what it's worth, I think you're completely wrong to think there's any ambiguity over whether it's a specific instance or not. It isn't, therefore there's no "poetic point" involved on that score. The very opposite, in fact, since everything about the entire paragraph repeatedly implies that these events are happening *again and again*, and are effectively having a mind-numbing effect on poor Enid, who is powerless to break out of the whole meaningless cycle.

Comment: Well, it seems unlikely that she would receive a "Third Notice from a medical lab demanding immediate payment of $0.22 while simultaneously showing an account balance of $0.00 carried forward" more than once, doesn't it?

Comment: Let's not get too bogged down with "likelihood" here - it's just fiction. That particular bit makes no sense to me anyway. The writer wants to imply computerised accounting systems send out meaningless demands for a few cents unpaid - but if that *did* happen, the computer's "balance" would thus have to show **-$0.22** (a *negative* amount reflecting what's outstanding). Obviously Franzen writes novels, not accounting software.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6412/discussion-between-missing-bob-and-fumblefingers)